# ALTER TABLE on entire database, in one go

Tags: mysql, magento

After having an awful experience with a dedicated server and spending 3 whole days repairing corrupted databases (Yes I know.... backup!).... I have narrowed the issues down to a few websites. The trouble is, these websites are Magento websites.

I am having to import the .ibd files into the `/var/lib/mysql` folder and DISCARD/IMPORT the tablespace.

Is there a way to alter ALL tables in the database at once, i.e `ALTER TABLE * DISCARD TABLESPACE` and then move the files across... Then `ALTER TABLE * IMPORT TABLESPACE` ?

Comment: A place to start => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874807/alter-all-tables-in-database and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35073/modify-all-tables-in-a-database-with-a-single-command

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a single call, but you can use MySQL to generate the calls for you, like this:

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT 
CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8;") 
AS MySQLCMD FROM TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_schema_here";
```

You can then use the output from the MySQL console to run these queries & you should be all set.